Why isn't striving for betterment considered opposition to Allah's will?
For example, if a parent has a disabled child, they shouldn't try to give medical treatment to their child to make them "normal."
Allah says in the Quran that He will test you with hunger and loss of property and lives (2:155). Taking this verse into consideration, no one should make an effort to overcome obstacles and hurdles that have been sent by Allah.
Striving for change means you are "challenging" the will of God indirectly. So why is it not considered disbelief? The only thing you should do is practice sabr (patience) and accept it as it is.

Because Allah has prescribed that people should strive and use the means He created to obtain benefits, doing so is in accordance with His will and does not go against it.
There are people who strive to find food and yet remain hungry and there are people who attempt to cure diseases and yet remain sick.
Accepting the will of Allah means that after you have exerted effort, you should accept the outcome and show patience if it is not to your liking. It does not mean that you must avoid trying altogether.
Seeking betterment by adopting the means that may lead to it is prescribed. For example:

Seeking healing through the means of medicine is permissible, as evident from:

يخرج من بطونها شراب مختلف ألوانه فيه شفاء للناس
There emerges from their bellies a drink, varying in colors, in which there is healing for people.
— Quran 16:69
فيه شفاء للناس دليل على جواز التعالج بشرب الدواء وغير ذلك
This verse is evidence for the permissibility of treating ailments by drinking medicine and other methods
— Tafsir al-Qurtubi


فقالوا يا رسول الله أنتداوى فقال تداووا فإن الله عز وجل لم يضع داء إلا وضع له دواء غير داء واحد الهرم
They asked: O Messenger of Allah, should we make use of medical treatment?
He replied: Make use of medical treatment, for Allah has not made a disease without appointing a remedy for it, with the exception of one disease, namely old age.
— Abu Dawud


Seeking sustenance by exerting effort is permissible, as evident from:

وما أرسلنا قبلك من المرسلين إلا إنهم ليأكلون الطعام ويمشون في الأسواق
And We did not send before you, [O Muhammad], any of the messengers except that they ate food and walked in the markets
— Quran 25:20
ويمشون في الأسواق أي : للتكسب والتجارة
They used to go around in the marketplaces seeking to engage in trade and earn a livelihood
— Tafsir Ibn Kathir


ما أكل أحد طعاما قط خيرا من أن يأكل من عمل يده، وإن نبي الله داود ـ عليه السلام ـ كان يأكل من عمل يده
Nobody has ever eaten a better meal than that which one has earned by working with one's own hands. The Prophet f Allah, David (عليه السلام) used to eat from the earnings of his manual labor.
— Bukhari


Seeking victory in battle through means such as engaging in combat and having weapons, armor and vehicles and taking precautions etc. is prescribed, as evident by:

يا أيها الذين آمنوا خذوا حذركم فانفروا ثبات أو انفروا جميعا
O you who have believed, take your precaution and [either] go forth in companies or go forth all together.
— Quran 4:71


وعلمناه صنعة لبوس لكم لتحصنكم من بأسكم
And We taught him the fashioning of coats of armor to protect you from your [enemy in] battle.
— Quran 21:80


وأعدوا لهم ما استطعتم من قوة ومن رباط الخيل ترهبون به عدو الله وعدوكم وآخرين من دونهم لا تعلمونهم الله يعلمهم
And prepare against them whatever you are able of power and of steeds of war by which you may terrify the enemy of Allah and your enemy and others besides them whom you do not know [but] whom Allah knows.
— Quran 8:60


Exerting effort to alleviate hunger in case of famine is permissible, as evident by:

فمن اضطر في مخمصة غير متجانف لإثم فإن الله غفور رحيم
But whoever is forced by severe hunger with no inclination to sin - then indeed, Allah is Forgiving and Merciful.
— Quran 5:3

As Allah has permitted eating halal food to satiate hunger, and has even permitted eating haram food in case of absolute necessity - He has not obligated us to patiently suffer death by starvation if there is some alternate available.

Taking steps to provide resources for use in the future is permissible, as evident by:

وتزودوا فإن خير الزاد التقوى
And take provisions (for the journey of Hajj), but indeed, the best provision is fear of Allah
— Quran 2:197
كان أهل اليمن يحجون ولا يتزودون ويقولون نحن المتوكلون، فإذا قدموا مكة سألوا الناس، فأنزل الله تعالى وتزودوا فإن خير الزاد التقوى
The people of Yemen used to come for Hajj and used not to bring enough provisions with them and used to say that they depend on Allah. On their arrival in Makkah they used to beg the people, and so Allah revealed, "And take a provision (with you) for the journey, but the best provision is the fear of Allah." (2.197).
— Bukhari


قال تزرعون سبع سنين دأبا فما حصدتم فذروه في سنبله إلا قليلا مما تأكلون ثم يأتي من بعد ذلك سبع شداد يأكلن ما قدمتم لهن إلا قليلا مما تحصنون
[Joseph] said, "You will plant for seven years consecutively; and what you harvest leave in its spikes, except a little from which you will eat. Then will come after that seven difficult [years] which will consume what you saved for them, except a little from which you will store.
— Quran 12:47-48
وهو يدل على جواز احتكار الطعام إلى وقت الحاجة
This is evidence that it is permitted to stockpile food for use in times of need
— Tafsir al-Qurtubi



There are also many other texts which evidence that it is allowed to strive to obtain what one requires such as the verses of the Quran: 2:267, 8:69,  19:25,  67:15 etc.
